# How to emulate real device Build.HARDWARE in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm currently trying to emulate real device on my android emulator.
I run AVD with `emulator -avd Pixel_6_Pro_API_31 -writable-system` command, then i root device with `avd root` and remount with `avd remount` and reboot device. Then i use `avd pull system/build.prop` to pool prop file and modify properties i need and push this file back to image. This work fine for couple properties such as `ro.system.build.id` and `ro.system.build.fingerprint` and calling `Build.ID` and `Build.FINGERPRINT` return changed values.
But how can i change value for Build.HARDWARE from 'ranchu' to any custom value. I have already tried to add `ro.hardware` property and using `setprop` command, but nothing helped

I want to call Build.HARDWARE and return custom value for this. Or are there any alternative ways to emulate real device fingerprint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, ro property is written during compilation and cannot be modified again. If you want to modify it, you can only change the relevant source code

Comment: But what files should I edit to change this property?

Comment: Are you using System. getProperties(). setProperty() and the error message is permission denied?

Comment: If so, I remember it seems like I want to modify the Selinux.cpp file

Comment: Actually i used `adb shell` then `su` then `setprop ro.hardware customvalue` and this say that read only property cannot be set

Comment: so,You can only modify the source code

Comment: This is not a reasonable requirement unless you can modify the source code

Comment: But where this Selinux.cpp is stored?

Comment: aha, buddy, you need to modify AOSP